# HTML table to java object

Tags: java, html, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

I need to convert html table to java Object. For now I cant find any good method for implementing this task. The example of table is below:

```
<table id='table'>
  <tr>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>address</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href=''>name1</a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href=''>Address</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

Also I expect to map the table to the next Object:

```
public class myClass {
    public String name;
    public String address;
}
```

I will be very thankfull if somebody help my with this task.

Comment: I don't quite understand, could you elaborate. Do you want to make a table object with fields name and address. So `Table {         Table(name, address){this.name, this.address;}                                                                              }` etc. (Sorry about the formatting)

Comment: I updated the question with object structure.

Comment: Better, but there are still a few more loose ends. Are you trying to use JSP? Are you trying to parse the html doc for the table's content and use it  to seed the members of your object?

Comment: I'm not trying to use jsp.The application just have to parse and transform static html files.

Answer (score 3):

I think in your case you want to use [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/), a nice Java library for parsing web pages. Once you have parsed the data you want from the wepage using Jsoup's selectors creating a Java object with it should be non-trivial. Here are a few helpful links:

- [jsoup tutorial](http://www.javatpoint.com/jsoup-tutorial)
- [try jsoup](http://try.jsoup.org/)

> File input = new File("table.html");
>
> ```
> Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8", "http://somewebsite.com/");
>
> Elements row1name = doc.select("tr"); 
>
> Elements row1address = doc.select("tr");
>
> MyClass table1 = new MyClass(row1name, row1address);
> ```

Something like that (the selectors are for row1name and address are wrong, you have to look at the docs to verify the proper way to do it...I don't remember). I hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

My answer won't probably be useful to the writer of this question (I am 3 years late so not the right timing I guess) but I think it will probably be useful for many other developers that might come across this answer.

Today, I just released (in the name of my company) an HTML to POJO complete framework that you can use to map HTML to any POJO class with simply some annotations. The library itself is quite handy and features many other things all the while being very pluggable. You can have a look to it right here : https://github.com/whimtrip/jwht-htmltopojo

### How to use : Basics

Imagine we need to parse the following html page :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>A Simple HTML Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="restaurant">
            <h1>A la bonne Franquette</h1>
            <p>French cuisine restaurant for gourmet of fellow french people</p>
            <div class="location">
                <p>in <span>London</span></p>
            </div>
            <p>Restaurant n*18,190. Ranked 113 out of 1,550 restaurants</p>  
            <div class="meals">
                <div class="meal">
                    <p>Veal Cutlet</p>
                    <p rating-color="green">4.5/5 stars</p>
                    <p>Chef Mr. Frenchie</p>
                </div>

                <div class="meal">
                    <p>Ratatouille</p>
                    <p rating-color="orange">3.6/5 stars</p>
                    <p>Chef Mr. Frenchie and Mme. French-Cuisine</p>
                </div>

            </div> 
        </div>    
    </body>
</html>
```

Let's create the POJOs we want to map it to :

```
public class Restaurant {

    @Selector( value = "div.restaurant > h1")
    private String name;

    @Selector( value = "div.restaurant > p:nth-child(2)")
    private String description;

    @Selector( value = "div.restaurant > div:nth-child(3) > p > span")    
    private String location;    

    @Selector( 
        value = "div.restaurant > p:nth-child(4)"
        format = "^Restaurant n\*([0-9,]+). Ranked ([0-9,]+) out of ([0-9,]+) restaurants$",
        indexForRegexPattern = 1,
        useDeserializer = true,
        deserializer = ReplacerDeserializer.class,
        preConvert = true,
        postConvert = false
    )
    // so that the number becomes a valid number as they are shown in this format : 18,190
    @ReplaceWith(value = ",", with = "")
    private Long id;

    @Selector( 
        value = "div.restaurant > p:nth-child(4)"
        format = "^Restaurant n\*([0-9,]+). Ranked ([0-9,]+) out of ([0-9,]+) restaurants$",
        // This time, we want the second regex group and not the first one anymore
        indexForRegexPattern = 2,
        useDeserializer = true,
        deserializer = ReplacerDeserializer.class,
        preConvert = true,
        postConvert = false
    )
    // so that the number becomes a valid number as they are shown in this format : 18,190
    @ReplaceWith(value = ",", with = "")
    private Integer rank;

    @Selector(value = ".meal")    
    private List<Meal> meals;

    // getters and setters

}
```

And now the `Meal` class as well :

```
public class Meal {

    @Selector(value = "p:nth-child(1)")
    private String name;

    @Selector(
        value = "p:nth-child(2)",
        format = "^([0-9.]+)\/5 stars$",
        indexForRegexPattern = 1
    )
    private Float stars;

    @Selector(
        value = "p:nth-child(2)",
        // rating-color custom attribute can be used as well
        attr = "rating-color"
    )
    private String ratingColor;

    @Selector(
        value = "p:nth-child(3)"
    )
    private String chefs;

    // getters and setters.
}
```

We provided some more explanations on the above code on our github page.

For the moment, let's see how to scrap this.

```
private static final String MY_HTML_FILE = "my-html-file.html";

public static void main(String[] args) {


    HtmlToPojoEngine htmlToPojoEngine = HtmlToPojoEngine.create();

    HtmlAdapter<Restaurant> adapter = htmlToPojoEngine.adapter(Restaurant.class);

    // If they were several restaurants in the same page, 
    // you would need to create a parent POJO containing
    // a list of Restaurants as shown with the meals here
    Restaurant restaurant = adapter.fromHtml(getHtmlBody());

    // That's it, do some magic now!

}


private static String getHtmlBody() throws IOException {
    byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(MY_HTML_FILE));
    return new String(encoded, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

}
```

Another short example can be found [here](https://github.com/Louis-wht/jwht-htmltopojo-booking-example)

Hope this will help someone out there!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!  =)

Comment: You're welcome! Glad to share this project with anyone interested in it! Any feedback is welcome as well :)

Comment: @Louis-wht The framework that you developed is very useful. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solution is to use XSLT. So for serializing html data to java object you can follow next steps::

- Transform HTML to XML document using the XSLT rules.
- Deserialise XML to java object.

This solution doesn't work if your html page has unclosed tags so you need to use some validation libraries before first step. In the case when your html is not valid Is much easier to use Jsoup, @coderrick described how to use it in [another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31053526/873063) answer.